# PDO возвращает SQLSTATE 00000

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Не могу понять, почему pdo_mysql возвращает SQLSTATE 00000:

```
$query_ban_appeals = prepare("SELECT *, COUNT(*) AS `total_ban_appeals` FROM ``ban_appeals``
        LEFT JOIN ``bans`` ON `ban_id` = ``bans``.`id`
        LEFT JOIN ``mods`` ON ``bans``.`creator` = ``mods``.`id`
        WHERE `denied` != 1 ".($local ? " AND ``bans``.`board` = :board " : " AND ``bans``.`board` IS NULL ")." ORDER BY `time`");
$query_ban_appeals->bindValue(':board', $mod['boards'][0]);

$query_ban_appeals->execute() or error(db_error($query));
$row_ban_appeals = $query_ban_appeals->fetch();
```

По идее, `SQLSTATE 00000` означает, что запрос в базу был выполнен успешно, но по запросу ничего не было найдено. Тогда почему тригерится ошибка? Или я чего-то не понимаю?

Comment: попробуйте добавить ```PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION```

Comment: prepare вам ошибку вернуть должен. Вы его код возврата не проверяете. Удвоенные апострофы синтаксически некорректны в запросе.